# How to unlock number lock in android 6.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

when i removed the SD card and restarted my smartphone , oddly the pattern lock that i had set was no more and i got a number lock instead.

I tried [using googles device locater](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?u=0) but it could not locate my device. How do I unlock my phone now

Answer (score 1):

enter in the numbers of in the same order and location as where the dots would have been in the pattern unlock EG

```
...   123
... = 456
...   789
```

so if you pattern was a square then you number pin would be 13269874 that would be a square starting at the top left corner. if this dose not work for you then you can always flash stock img with cmd and restore form back up

Comment: OK,  i tried all combination of numbers it did not work.tried factory reset but still get the pin lock

Comment: do you have TWRP installed if so you can try this http://www.howtogeek.com/240657/how-to-fix-pin-errors-after-restoring-from-twrp-android-backups/